# Limit inferior/superior of a function and its inverse

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I'm having a trouble with the veracity of the following statement: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Assuming that $f$ and $\dfrac{1}{f}$ are bounded in a neighborhood of $a$:$$\limsup_{x\to a^{+}}(f)=\left(\liminf_{x\to a^{+}}\dfrac{1}{f}\right)^{-1}$$ I think it's false but I can't come with a counterexample. In case it's true, can you give me any hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look, for example, at an $f$ that takes only the values $1$ and $-2$ infinitely many times in every right neighborhood of $a$. The limsup is $1$ the liminf of $1/f$ is $-1/2$ and the reciprocal of that is $-2$.

Comment: Thanks @conditionalMethod .... do you think it's true if we impose that $f>0$ ?

Comment: Yes, for a positive function, or for a negative function, it will be true. The thing is that in that case the reciprocal will change all inequalities between values of $f$ at the same time.

Comment: @kccu It appears to me that your candidate fits the equality in question. Did you forget the $^{-1}$ in the second expression?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.